# Tools and practices to make a large ASP.NET web application section-508-compliant

Tags: asp.net, section508

We're about to migrate an existing large ASP.NET web application to make it [section-508 compliant](http://www.section508.gov/index.cfm?FuseAction=Content&ID=3).  Are there any recommended tools and practices that can be employed for this kind of project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ensure the application can function correctly without the use of JavaScript. You may find you have to cut down on the use of the built in ASP.NET server controls to do this.
- Ensure the HTML is valid, and makes full use of elements such as labels to give meaning to all the inputs etc..
- You may wish to consider using ASP.NET MVC as it gives you much more control over the final HTML rendered. Alternativly [CSS Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/) can be used instead.
- If your application requires an XHTML editor it may be worth looking at [XStandard](http://www.xstandard.com/). This editor provides an accessible interface and generates compliant XHTML (without requiring JavaScript), the downside is that it's a browser plug-in, so it may not be suitable for your application.

Comment: Why do you need to eliminate Javascript? The aim is to prevent physical barriers to handicapped users. Smart use of Javascript seems to be a valid technique to *improve* accessability.

Comment: I don't eliminate it - JavaScript can add a lot to an application. I just try and make sure that the app works without it in case a non JavaScript enabled browser (such as a text reader) is being used (or it's switched off).